# Number of neighbors as a function of dimension

Tags: pca, graph-theory, self-organizing-maps

I apologize in advance for perhaps an imprecise formulation of the question.

If I have a point in 1D, it has precisely 2 nearest neighbors independent of choices.

In 2D, if I allow arbitrary orientation then there is an infinite amount of neighbors, but if I discretize on a grid I have either 4 (von Neumann neighborhood) or 8 (Moore neighborhood) or some other choice.

In 3D, arbitrary orientation has a larger infinity (but is it infinitely larger than the 2D case?), and if I discretize on a grid I have 6 (von Neumann neighborhood) or 26 (Moore neighborhood) or some other choice.

In n-dimensions, for example, von Neumann neighborhood goes as 2n, but what are other common choices? What are the typical ways to think about number of neighbors as a function of dimensions in Euclidean space.

If we use a "topology preserving" dimensional reduction (PCA/SOM), then clearly the number of neighbors a point has decreases, what is a good way of thinking of what is preserved?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you expand on the statistical question here?

Comment: What would "common choices" mean?  For what purposes?  Among what communities?  It is unclear what you mean by "topology-preserving," since any dimensional reduction fundamentally changes the topology of the space.

Comment: @ whuber. By "topology preserving" in PCA/SOM I mean neighboring points in the higher dimensional space tend to remain close in the lower dimensional space. Suppose you have some 10 dimensional space, you can find the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix (PCA) and try to map points in the 10 dimensional space with the two highest eigenvalue eigenvectors. The resulting mapping will 2D however points that are close to each other in the 10D space will be ingeneral close to each other in the 2D space as well. 
Edit: in communities of people thinking about ML/cellular automata/graph theory.

Comment: @mdewey. I asked this question originally in the math stack but they referred me to here since som/pca/dimension reduction is something more related to ML/stats, or so they said. A more stat's-based question would be is there  a way to evaluate the effect of dimensionality of the data on its information content. As an example of the PCA, when you take the first components to map a high dimensional space, what information is lost because  a linear mapping doesn't describe the data, and what information is lost because a lower dimensional space does not describe the data.

Answer (score 1):

First off, even in 1-D a nearest neighbor may not be unique, since two observations may occupy the same coordinate space, or be equidistant on either side of the line. It is not difficult, then, to see that an infinite number of concentric observations can be "nearest neighbors" in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and similarly for spheres and hyperspheres in higher dimensions.

Furthermore, you are confusing [taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) for Euclidean. Indeed, in taxicab geometry, there are 4 possible distinct locations for nearest neighbors in 2 dimensions having 1 "block" of distance, but 2 or more blocks of distance gives more than 4 possible nearest neighbors coordinates. However, in Euclidean space, the distance norm is always defined as $d = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \| x_i^2\|}$ for any dimensionality $n$ and coordinates $<x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n>$ and there are measurably infinite nearest neighbors for non-concentric observations in 2 space or higher.

Comment: I don't think the OP confuses the $L^1$ and $L^2$ metrics. On a discrete orthogonal grid of common spacing $h$ in all $n$ dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the number of neighbors of any point within a *Euclidean* distance $h$ is precisely $2n$.

Comment: "If I discretize on a grid [...] or some other choice" is not a very specific description of the geometry in the OP's mind.

Comment: @Bernhard Don't the references to the [types of neighborhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) make the intention clear?